# how in Pry (or other tool) would I see the source code for ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I saw a friend do this and it was pretty slick. He opened a rails console session using Pry and I think he cd'd to rails and was able to do a show-source Base.

Within my app, I can do:

```
>rails c
(pry)>show-source User # shows User

>show-source Pry # shows /gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb
```

But how would I show ActiveRecord::Base?

```
[2] pry(main)> cd Rails
[3] pry(Rails):1> show-source ActiveRecord::Base
Error: Couldn't locate a definition for ActiveRecord::Base!
[5] pry(Rails):1> cd ActiveRecord
[6] pry(ActiveRecord):2> show-source Base
Error: Couldn't locate a definition for Base!
[7] pry(ActiveRecord):2>
```

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to show https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb using either an editor or less in the currect console session. What would be the best way to do this either via Pry or other tool?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/ lets you set breakpoints on and step through all of the external libraries for your app. It is extremely slick and easy to use.

Comment: thx Brad... I used RubyMine in past. Was hoping to stay in terminal. I think it has something to do with a bundler path

Comment: thx - just removed it.